# When i add hit detection my canvas disapears

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a small js game just for fun.

But whenever I add hit detection to my cube, my entire canvas disappears. I have no idea what might be causing that and therefore I'm asking here. I'll add two snippets. One before I add the hit detection and one after. I hope someone can help me.

```js
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 500;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },    
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();    
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = -2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speed= 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speed= -2; }
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}
```

And  here is the one where I added an obstacle and hit detection

If you were to put this into a canvas (in HTML) the entire canvas would disappear or at least that's what happens to me.

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 225, 225);
    myObstacle = new component(40, 40, "green", 300, 120); 
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 500;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },    
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore();    
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    }
     }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
    (mytop > otherbottom) ||
    (myright < otherleft) ||
    (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }


function updateGameArea() {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    myGameArea.stop();
  } else {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update();
    myGamePiece.moveAngle = 0;
    myGamePiece.speed = 0;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = -2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.moveAngle = 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speed= 2; }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speed= -2; }
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Check your curly braces; you're closing a function too early. Also, this is essentially a duplicate of your previous question. It might get closed because of that. If you want proper answers, at the very least make sure we aren't immediately greeted by a syntax error when we try to run your snippet. And add the HTML to we have a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied your 2nd code snippet, I noticed **the code was missing brackets** in some places. Therefore I didn't have a canvas either.

So, there was an extra one after:

```
this.newPos = function() {
    this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
    this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
    this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
}
 } <-- //This guy
```

You were missing one at the end of the component function:

```
    }
    return crash;
  }
"}" <-- //This one is missing
```

And to finish up you're missing the closing one of your `updateGameArea()` function:

```
    myGamePiece.update();
    }
"}" <-- //This one is missing too
```

After that I just moved myGameArea object at the start with the other ones (not mandatory, but it's good to have all your variables together), called:

```
startGame()
```

and voilà !

Those kind of errors won't really show up in the console, but you can notice them by running some *auto-format/auto-indentation* on your code. **If the code is not indented well** after that, **there is a good chance you missed a bracket**.

Comment: Got mixed up, meant braces went I said brackets.